two-way binding of a checkbox does not happen
For the code posted below vue component it is a child component and is hosted in a specific parent. When I make two ways binding via vModelCheckGeoTIFFOverlayBandAverages by introducing a change to compPropsVModelCheckGeoTIFFOverlayBandAverages, the changes
do not get reflected in the parent component.
Am I making the binding of the checkbox wrong
code:
<template>
    <cds-checkbox id="idCheckboxGeoTIFFOverlayBandAveragesContainer">
        <label id="idTextGeoTIFFOverlayBandAverages">{{ tempTextBandAverages }}</label>
        <input
            type="checkbox"
            :value="compPropsVModelCheckGeoTIFFOverlayBandAverages"
            @input="$emit('update:compPropsVModelCheckGeoTIFFOverlayBandAverages', $event.target.checked)"
            :disabled="isCheckboxGeoTIFFOverlayBandAveragesDisabled"
            :checked="compPropsVModelCheckGeoTIFFOverlayBandAverages"
            @change="onCheckboxGeoTIFFOverlayBandAveragesChanged"
        />
    </cds-checkbox>
</template>

<script>
import { GeoTIFFOverlaySettingsConstants } from '../../../resources/....';
import { StoreOnCheckboxBandAveragesStatusChanged } from '../../../../../...';

let msg = null;

export default {
    name: 'SentinelHubGeoTIFFOverlayBand1',
    data() {
        return {
            refStoreOnCheckboxBandAveragesStatusChanged: StoreOnCheckboxBandAveragesStatusChanged,
            isCheckboxChecked: false,
            tempTextBandAverages: GeoTIFFOverlaySettingsConstants.CONST_STRING_BAND_1_AVERAGES.description,
        };
    },
    components: {},
    props: {
        isCheckboxGeoTIFFOverlayBandAveragesDisabled: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: true,
        },
        vModelCheckGeoTIFFOverlayBandAverages: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: null,
        },
    },
    emits: {
        'update:vModelCheckGeoTIFFOverlayBandAverages':null,
    },
    computed: {
        compPropsVModelCheckGeoTIFFOverlayBandAverages: {
            get() {
                return this.vModelCheckGeoTIFFOverlayBandAverages;
            },
            set(value) {
                this.$emit('update:vModelCheckGeoTIFFOverlayBandAverages', value);
            },
        },
    },
    watch: {
        isCheckboxChecked(newVal, oldVal) {
            this.compPropsVModelCheckGeoTIFFOverlayBandAverages = newVal;
        },
    },
    methods: {
        async onCheckboxGeoTIFFOverlayBandAveragesChanged() {
            this.isCheckboxChecked = !this.isCheckboxChecked;
            await this.refStoreOnCheckboxBandAveragesStatusChanged.actions.init();
            this.refStoreOnCheckboxBandAveragesStatusChanged.setters.set(this.isCheckboxChecked);
        },
    },
};
</script>

explained above in the question

As noted in earlier questions, there's a mess with a writable computed and direct use of props and events, similar problems occured there too. You don't really need a writable computed here. It makes it more complicated. The complex naming doesn't help it, too. It's not conventional to give long names like "vModelCheckGeoTIFFOverlayBandAverages", they are confusing and hard to distinguish. There's already a convention to follow for v-model, "modelValue" prop and "update:modelValue" event. This component operates on 1 value, it suits this convention.

@EstusFlask would you please provide enhanced version of the code that i can use it as a template or a reference for any prospective use?

The reason it doesn't work here is that you don't use set() in a writable computed, making it useless. Instead the event is emitted, update:compPropsVModelCheckGeoTIFFOverlayBandAverages, this "compProps..." is the computed's name, while the event's name is "update:vModelCheckGeoTIFFOverlayBandAverages". That bad naming causes mistakes and make you confuse things suggests it's a real problem and not just a matter of taste. I'd suggest to use the code I posted in previous questions for this component, I'm quite sure it was workable and the naming was fixed,these questions were probably deleted?

@EstusFlask appreciate you help, but is it possible to transalte the words in your last comment into code please, that will be more helpful and great, please

@EstusFlask unfortunately, I can not find these question you were insinuating for. Referring to your last comment, you mentioned that I did not use ‘set’ of the writable computed property! But I did use it,  am I mistaken?

I stand corrected, it looks like there was another account and the questions weren't deleted. Also you're correct about set(), it's triggered here this.isCheckboxChecked = !this.isCheckboxChecked, so the problem could be in the parent.

Regarding the previous comment, I sorted this out but already forgot when writing it. The problem is that you expect set() to be called in @change. But it's not called on inputs. Only @input is called, and emits update:compPropsVModelCheckGeoTIFFOverlayBandAverages event that does nothing. Not dealing with low-level DOM implementation is a good reason to stick to v-model for native elements, as noted in the answer

An input emits update:compPropsVModelCheckGeoTIFFOverlayBandAverages event, while the name of the event is update:vModelCheckGeoTIFFOverlayBandAverages. This shows the problem with long naming. v-model already suggests the convention, "modelValue" prop and "update:modelValue" event. As long as a component deals with one value, these names are unambiguous and can be conventionally used.
It's still beneficial to use it with v-model with native elements like input instead of direct use of props and events because this allows to skip low-level details like $event.target.checked and make code shorter and less error-prone.
It's unclear if the component requires to have its own local state. If it's not needed, there's no need for data() for component state, and the names can be kept short and intelligible:
<label id="idTextGeoTIFFOverlayBandAverages">{{ labelText }}</label>
<input
  type="checkbox"
  v-model="isChecked"
  :disabled="disabled"
/>

and
props: {
    modelValue: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false,
    },
    disabled: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false,
    },
},
emits: {
    'update:modelValue':null,
},
data() {
    return {
        labelText: GeoTIFFOverlaySettingsConstants.CONST_STRING_BAND_1_AVERAGES.description,
    };
},
computed: {
    isChecked: {
        get() {
            return this.modelValue;
        },
        set(value) {
            this.$emit('update:modelValue', value);
        },
    },
},
watch: {
    isChecked(newVal, oldVal) {
      // can be used to do anything on value updates, e.g. sync a store
    },
}

And is supposed to be used as:
Or without v-model, the usage is more straightforward than with input:
<SentinelHubGeoTIFFOverlayBand1
  :modelValue="someValue"
  @update:modelValue="updateSomeValue"
  :disabled="someDisabled"/>


Thnk you very much, I will acknowledge once tested

But why, when I follow the same pattern as mentioned in my original question, with reading-button it works?is there an peculiarities to the checkbox please

Can you clarify about reading-button, which one do you mean?

Sorry, I meant, radio button. It was the auto correction.i mean, I have been following the same pattern in my original question  but with radio-buttons, and it was working as expected

No fundamental difference between them, needs to be checked how they were different. It could be workable with some differences. The primary problem is that the whole code is unnecessarily convoluted, makes it easy to make mistakes and hard to find them

morning, i introduce changes to the original question, because the value the i change in the child component, despite i used the same code in my original question, gets refelected in the subparent component but never gets reflected in the grand or the main parent. should i just update the question or post anew one please

Sure, consider posting a new question, add a link to this one if it's related
